# How to manage data in an offline Android app in kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room, offline

I want to make an android app that works offline. For the data part, I want to have some data in a json file, and whenever my app is open firstly that JSON file is fetched, and from the fetched data I want to make tables entries in android room database(offline). So that, let say if user liked some quotes, then i can change the state of that quote as liked in room db, and when user clicked on Liked Quotes navigation, I can show those offline stored quotes which were liked (OfCourse when user delete the app that data will be lost). The problem I'm facing is where to fetch that data file and create entries in room db. If I  do this in onCreate() then whenever user will open this app the duplicate entries will be created everytime. How to make those entries only ones?

Comment: You can create a flag and save it in sharedpref. For the first time this sharePref value will be true so you can make API call and fetch json, after fetching json you can update this key to false, this way you can avoid API call on each app launch.

Comment: Thanks @Parmesh, It's an easy and light way to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's several ways to do it. One way is to include a random UUID in each element, and make that column in the DB have a UNIQUE constraint.  Then re-adding it will fail (alternatively you can use an UPSERT and then it will automatically update the data in case the data changed).

Another way is to just not process the file if it already exists in onCreate. Your logic can be

```
if(network_exists) {
   copy_file_from_network()
}
else if(json file exists) {
   return
}
else {
  copy_file_from_assets()
}
process_json_file()
```

Actually I can see a good argument for doing both-  that way if there are updates to existing rows you process them, but if there's no new data you don't waste your time.

As for a good place to put this-  I'd be running this during your splash screen if you have one, so the user has an indication that you may be processing for a while.

Comment: Hey I'm new in Android, Can you please elaborate the 2nd method? is the  `json file exists`  check is checking that the data is already stored in RoomDB or not, or something else?

Comment: @RahulKumawat No, its checking whether the actual file exists on disk.  So the initial file is in your assets.  When you first run onCreate, there is no file on disk (and you can't just download it) you copy it from assets to disk.  Then you process the file.  The reason for the copy is both so you can skip this if you've already done it before, and so you can process it the same way as in the case where you download it.  I do recommend using the UUIDs as well, as that will allow you to change rows in subsequent downloads.